# Mod_rewrite as access control - how to pass through all page resources?

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am using mod_rewrite on Apache as access control. The rules are set up such that if a user is not logged in he will be unable to access most pages. Certain pages (that all have a *.php extension) are chosen as "public pages" by the site's administrators. A "public page" DOES grant permission to non-logged in users.

Various pictures and other resources that are not granted explicit permission to be public are not accessible by anon users; they send the user to the main page. This is exactly the behavior I want.

The problem is that these public pages have all sorts of embedded elements, linked from distant directories. These elements are denied by the same rewrite rules.

**Is it possible to pass-through any requests for resources originating from a rewritten page, but keep them blocked off otherwise?**

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to pass-through any requests for resources originating from a rewritten page, but keep them blocked off otherwise?

You can do an additional check against the `%{HTTP_REFERER}` var in a `RewriteCond` to allow access if the referer is a URL that is a php page (or whatever other public pages). The problem with doing it this way is referers can be spoofed. It'll look something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(http://your-domain.com)?/path/to/public\.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(http://your-domain.com)?/path/to/another-public\.php$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(http://your-domain.com)?/public/stuff/.*\.php$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

The rule itself may be different depending on your existing rules (this one just passes the request through if the referer matches one of the above).